# <font> tag within <select> not rendering correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I have been expirementing with the Google Translate tools (http://translate.google.com/translate_tools). They seem to work fine, except it seems that everything that gets translated is wrapped in two `<font>` tags. When this is within a `<select>`, Firefox does not render the selected item within the list.

I assume that the `<font>` tag is not allowed within an `<option>` tag, as when starting off with the following markup, the `<font>` is not shown within firebug:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected"><font><font>Test</font></font></option>
    <option><font><font>Test 2</font></font></option>
    <option><font><font>Test 3</font></font></option>
    <option><font><font>Test 4</font></font></option>
</select>
```

If I add some jQuery to add the `<font>` tags on DOM load, then the `<font>` tags appear but the text within disappears. Looking within firebug, it's almost as if they are positioned wrong.

A [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Jgc/). Seems like IE, Chrome and Opera all ignore the `<font>` tag regardless of whether it is injected via jQuery.

Comment: Is there a way to fix Firefox's rendering?

Comment: The `font` is already deprecated in HTML4. Are *you* using them, or are they generated by the tools?

Comment: I didnt even know that the font tag exists :D

Comment: Generated by the translate_tools....

Comment: Then You should truncate the font tag by passing the output of the tools to manual function to be defined by u

Comment: @MiG: I think you should write a bug report. And ask them why they use it. This would be at least interesting to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [HTML5 spec on the `option` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-option-element):

> Content model: Text.

["Text" is defined as](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#text-content):

> **Text, in the context of content models, means text nodes.** Text is
>   sometimes used as a content model on its own, but is also phrasing
>   content, and can be inter-element whitespace (if the text nodes are
>   empty or contain just space characters).

So, due to `font` being an invalid child of `option`, browsers are error correcting by removing `font`.

Comment: I know. I was wondering why Firefox does not. Check the JSFiddle in Firefox 6.0 and the tags still remain. I cannot control the generated output of what google translate is doing. I was mearly wondering if this could be fixed.

Comment: I'm not *quite* following - how are you making Google generate this output?

Comment: This was already the case in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) btw.

Comment: Never mind - I figured it out. This breaks in Firefox 6 as you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pDXNd/. This is more like a bug with Google Translate, to be honest. Though I can see why you're trying to fix it :)

Comment: if you follow the link to the google translate tools, when you translate the dummy page, all translations are wrapped in two `font` tags. Indeed it is a Google translate problem. But seen as all the other browsers behave themselves :)

Comment: @MiG: The closest I could come to a fix is this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/nzkYA/. I personally wouldn't use it, it's very fragile (if it runs, it breaks translating back to English or to a different language for `select`s).

Comment: Thats what I thought, writing a JS to fix a bodge in the first place never seems like a good idea. I might get round to filling a bug report with Google...